# Transform string array to csv mulesoft 4.1.2

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have Array of Strings, want to convert it into a csv output in mule 4.1.2. Sample input payload is as below -

[ "{\n "id": 123,\n "name": "ABC",\n "communication": "email"\n}", "{\n "id": 123,\n "name": "ABC",\n "communication": "paper"\n}" ]

I need csv output with columns as

MemberId Person Name Communcation 
123 ABC email

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the strings are properly formatted? Looks like your quotes are not properly escaped. If I tried to edit myself I'd just be taking a random stab at it.

Comment: following is corrected one - 
[ "{\n \"id\": \"123\",\n \"name\": \"ABC\",\n \"communication\": \"email\"\n}", "{\n \"id\": \"123\",\n \"name\": \"ABC\",\n \"communication\": \"paper\"\n}" ]

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple using DataWeave

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv headerLineNumber = 0 , header = true
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    MemberId: payload01.id as String,
    "Person Name": payload01.name,
    Communication: payload01.communication
}
```

Comment: Tried it but getting error -  Message  : "You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
  1: Binary ("{\n  \"id\": 123,\n  \"name\": \"ABC\",\n  \"communication\": \...)
  2: Name ("id")
But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Name)
  (Array, String)
  (Date, Name)
  (DateTime, Name)
  (LocalDateTime, Name)
  (LocalTime, Name)
  (Object, Name)
  (Object, String)
  (Period, Name)
  (Time, Name)

5|     MemberId : payload01.id,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Trace:
  at main (line: 5, column: 16)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0

Comment: You need to get that input properly formatted. Where does that input come from? Currently it is a list of JSON formatted strings, rather than a proper JSON array.

Comment: i am getting it as list of strings in Batch Aggregator component.